# How to make views out of partitions in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am using Sybase 12.5.3, have a table with 12 million rows without any identity/id column. I want to parallely bcp out the data from table to 12 different files.

- Found that this can only be done if I make views on the table and then run bcp parallely (Reference: [link](http://www.sypron.nl/quiz2012a.html)-February 2012 question)
- My table has partitions also and I have partition ids only (Not partition names)
- Is there any way I cam make 12 different views of 1 million rows each using either the partitions or using some counterpart of rownum of Oracle in sybase

Help will be really appreciated !!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just `bcp` out of the partitions?  There is not a `rownum` counterpart in Sybase, so without using `-F` & `-L` it would rely on you having some value in your data upon which you could divide the data into approximatly 1/12 of the data to create the views.  It will likely be very difficult to get exactly 1 million rows per file.

Comment: -F and -L options don't work as expected in parallel bcp out. reference:[link](http://www.sypron.nl/quiz2012a.html) - last question and its answer. Also I just want approximately 1 million rows and not strictly. I dont know how to bcp out of the partitons, if there is any way, please let me know!

Comment: Was a bit busy last few days! Thanks for the help, it saved a lot of time for me !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `bcp` out of the partitions, you can reference the partition name or partition number.

```
bcp mydb..bigtable:1 out file1 -Pmypassword -c &
bcp mydb..bigtable:2 out file2 -Pmypassword -c &
```

This would create a character (plaintext) output from partitions 1 & 2 of `bigtable`

Though much of the documentation [concentrates on importing data](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc30191_1251/html/utility/X37157.htm), the systax for exporting is typically very close.

Alternatively, you can create views based on the values in the tables.  Assuming there is a column that holds some sort of range (or catagorical) value that can be used to divide the data, you can use something like this:

```
create view mytable_VIEW_1 as
select * from bigtable
where myColumn < someValue1

create view mytable_VIEW_2 as
select * from bigtable
where myColumn between someValue2 and someValue3
```

Once your views are created, you can easily `bcp` out from them.